# Is there a way to call a method via Spring annotation?

Tags: java, spring-boot, annotations

I am new to Spring Boot, I am curious about if we can call a method via some annotation?

Classes have @Component("somevalue") annotation, is there a similar annotation (or create a custom annotation) for methods and call them (by this value String?).

I mean, if something like this is possible:

In class A

```
@CustomAnnotation("m1")
public void method1(){
}

@CustomAnnotation("m2")
public void method2(){
}
```

In class B

```
String identifier = "m2";
(magic here).call(A, identifier);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can find out the way to implement it by [`ReflectionUtils`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/ReflectionUtils.html).